# Printing the memory representation of an integer using char* and unsigned char*

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, char

I am stuck with a problem here. I entered an integer, casted the integer pointer and sent it into a function `print_bytes` which accepts a `char*` pointer and the number of bytes to be printed. Tried printing the address of each byte and the number in type hexadecimal. But with 250 the o/p should have been fa for the first byte and zeroes for next 3 bytes, but instead it prints fffffffa for the first byte.

```
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void print_bytes(char* ptr,int len)
{
      for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
      {
             printf("%p  %x\n",ptr+i,*(ptr+i));         
      }     
}
int main()
{
      int a=250;
      print_bytes((char*)&a,4);
      return 0;
}
```

But when I change the pointer type to `unsigned char*` it gives the correct output.
That means the MSB being one for `char*` is making the output go wrong. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is getting promoted to signed int when passed to the printf function. When a signed type is promoted, it's "sign-extended".

To an 8-bit *signed* char, the value 250 is equivalent to -6 (2's complement) and since it's signed, -6 is considered the "true" value.
When this is extended to a signed integer (4 bytes), as is happening here, the value -6 is preserved (through the sign-extension), rather than the value 250. But -6 on a 4 byte value is fffffffa, whereas it's merely fa on a single byte.

Since the MSB acts as a flag for the sign, if it's set,  you get the behaviour you've observed.

Casting to `(unsigned char)` on the printf call will cause the value to be "zero-extended" instead. This will cause the value 250 to be preserved, rather than the value -6, and will result in the behaviour you want.

It is a requirement of printf (as set by the standard), being a variadic function (vararg), that arguments narrower than an int be promoted to an int prior to being passed, hence the sign-extension in the first place. (It also requires the promotion of float to double).

Comment: do u know any resources from where one can get hold of such intricacies?

Comment: That's knowledge I obtained from looking at output assembler whilst helping out on a similar problem a while back. For instance, in your example you can clearly see a MOVSX (move, sign extend) instruction prior to the printf call. Casting to `unsigned char` causes this instruction to be replaced by a MOVZX. Presumably the C standard and/or various C books mention this somewhere.
If you're on Windows, the calculator program has a Programmer mode where you can observe the nature of 2's complement (and you can see sign-extension by switching the type size (BYTE -> WORD -> DWORD -> QWORD).

Comment: "cannot pass single byte values around" -- wrong. `char` is extended to `int` when the type of the argument is `int` or there's no prototype; since `printf` is varargs, there's no prototype for the arguments past the format.

Comment: The extension will occur regardless (this is behind the scenes, in the output assembler). If the argument to a function is of type `char` then it will be zero-extended prior to being pushed onto the stack, since a single byte alone *cannot* be pushed onto the stack on an x86 processor. The sign-extension comes from the signed-nature of int, but a char *must* be extended in someway to be passed around in memory.

Comment: That has nothing to do with anything here ... the value on the stack will be accessed as a single byte when evaluated by a function with a prototype. An implementation could even pass four single-char arguments in one word if it chose to.

Answer (score 0):

This is because (on your system) `char` is signed, and it's getting promoted to `int` in the `printf()` call.

Use `unsigned char`:

```
void print_bytes(const unsigned char *ptr, size_t len)
{
  for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    printf("%p  %x\n", ptr + i, ptr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The mask isn't necessary, and omitting it makes print_bytes work when chars aren't 8 bits.

Comment: And `for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) printf("%p  %x\n", ptr+i, ptr[i]);` is simpler.

Comment: @JimBalter Thanks, I edited. I like not adding extra variables when the arguments suffice, but perhaps it's clearer with an `i` (and more like the OP's code).

Comment: @unwind - if unsigned char does not get promoted to int... then what is the need for masking??

Comment: @user1969460 The masking isn't needed, the `unsigned char` will be promoted to `unsigned int`, but no sign-extension will happen since it's unsigned. This means e.g. `'\x80'` will be promoted to `0x80u`, instead of `0xffffff80` as before.

Comment: so when a char is promoted to int... is that the case that the 3 bytes from the left get filled with 1's??
because it is the case here... getting 6f's... and then the expected fa in the last byte...

Comment: See my answer, the char is sign-extended. So if the MSB is set, it treats the value as a negative number which results in the higher bits getting set (as per 2's complement notation).

Comment: @Karanpreet when `signed char` is promoted to `int` it is sign-extended. `char` can be equivalent to either `unsigned char` or `signed char` ... it's up to the implementation. (In your case, and most commonly, it's `signed char`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%p  %02x\n",ptr+i,(unsigned char)*(ptr+i));
```

Comment: How about `*(ptr+i)` -> `ptr[i]`